# Smart Location Library cache previous location

Tags: android, location

Is there any way to retrieve previous cached location on smart location library in case it's taking too long to get a new location? If it's not, what's the best procedure to save a new location to cache in order to use that later in similar case?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

```
public static Location getLastLocation(Context context){
        return SmartLocation.with(context)
                .location()
                .getLastLocation();
    }
```

this method will return the last saved best location